# "There is no place like" has two meanings

Tags: phrase-meaning

I've recently bought a shirt with motto *There is no place like 127.0.0.1*. I am usually asked (by people who don't understand english or ip address or both) what that phrase means. Sometimes, I put a bit effort in explaining what ip address is and what is special about *127.0.0.1*. To sum up my explanation I end up with *It just means "Home sweet home"*.

However, I realized it could mean two things.

> Amongst all places (including *127.0.0.1*) *127.0.0.1* is unique and no other place is simillar to it.

or

> If we consider all places, there (sadly) is no such place like *127.0.0.1*.

Where first would mean *Home sweet home* and second something like *127.0.0.1 is fake, nothing has such ip address (and eventually you can't hide on the Internet)*

Which explanation is correct and how would one rephrase the motto to mean the other one.

Comment: I think it's pretty clear the purpose of that 'joke' shirt is a pun for the old saying "There's no place like home". 127.0.0.1 is home. I think you're over-analyzing.

Comment: If there is no place like X, what exactly is X? Your first meaning would be the one assumed to be understood, unless context ( 'Don't be silly! There is no place like Mordor.') demanded otherwise.

Comment: What @Othya and Edwin said. In any "natural" context, only the (somewhat lame / geeky) pun on *Home sweet home* would be understood. But if you *wanted* the alternate meaning, you'd almost certainly express it as *There is **no such place** as 127.0.0.1* (whatever *that* might be supposed to mean).

Comment: Saw the t-shirt [here](http://www.tech-faq.com/127-0-0-1.html)

Comment: It should be pointed out that "There's no place like home" is an iconic sentence first from the 1823 song [Home! Sweet Home!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Home!_Sweet_Home!), and then (in addition to some others) the 1939 film [The Wizard of Oz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wizard_of_Oz_(1939_film)).  Undoubtedly, this was the intended reference for the T-shirt.  (Oops!  I guess Andrew Neely already mentioned this.)

Comment: “There's no place like 127.0.0.1” should obviously be read “There's no place like localhost”.

Comment: The usages here are ***like*** as a simile versus ***like*** to mean ***such as***. The first is for comparing two things and the second is for providing examples of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your original question, it means the same as your first interpretation, and cannot be misunderstood to mean the second one because "there is no such place like X" is not a phrasing used in English. The correct phrase to indicate that X doesn't exist would be "there is no such place **as** X".

Answer (score 2):

The best explanation of the English idiom "There's no place like home" is "Home is unique" or "Home sweet home."

The phrase originated in a [poem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Home!_Sweet_Home!)

> Mid pleasures and palaces though we may roam
>   Be it ever so humble, there's no place like home
>   A charm from the skies seems to hallow us there
>   Which seek thro' the world, is ne'er met elsewhere
>   Home! Home!
>   Sweet, sweet home!
>   There's no place like home
>   There's no place like home!

The phrase was also used in the [Wizard of Oz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wizard_of_Oz_(1939_film)) as the incantation to send Dorothy back home to Kansas.

With the poem talking about both how unique and sweet home is, we may safely say that the first interpretation is correct.

Answer (score 1):

127.0.0.1 is not unique but is local host of whatever computer you are in front of, so in reality it is "there is no place like where you are right now"
So.. it can be interpreted as:
"Live in the moment"
"Live for today"
"You are always where you are meant to be "
Etc.

Answer (score -3):

Seriously?

127.0.0.1 --> localhost --> your own machine (the one you are currently using and potentially have customized to your liking)

That means there is no place like my own machine.

There is no other place like my own machine would also work.

I think your mistake was to mistranslate in the first place. It does not say 127.0.0.1 sweet 127.0.0.1. So I don't know how you came up with "home sweet home".

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is not only mine machine but also yours, his and anyone elses

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I updated the answer. This is a humorous statement and should be taken as such. I'm pretty sure the person that came up with this phrase did not do research on how to avoid misunderstandings when reading this. ;)

Comment: You're missing the fact that one says "no such place as" instead of "no such place like" when denying the place's existence. This means that the phrase "There is no place like 127.0.0.1" cannot be misinterpreted as denying the existence of 127.0.0.1.